# Operators from list is still showing quotation marks when printed (Python 3.1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators, python-3.1

When I'm coding, I choose a random value from a list and print it alongside two numbers to make a sum. However, the value from the list still shows the quotation marks and I don't understand why. The code is:

```
import random
level = input('Please choose either easy, medium or hard')
if level == 'easy':
    num1 = random.randint(1,5)
    num2 = random.randint(1,5)
    #Chooses a random operator from the list
    op = random.choice(['+', '-', '*'])
    #Arranges it so the larger number is printed first
    if num1 > num2:
        sum1 = (num1, op, num2)
    else:
        sum1 = (num2, op, num1)
    #Prints the two numbers and the random operator
    print(sum1)
```

I try running this code and the result I am given is:

```
(4, '*', 3)
```

When I want it to appear as:

```
4*3
```

Those numbers are randomly generated also but work fine. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing a list, which produces this format. In order to get your desired output you could `join` the list with an empty delimiter:

```
print (''.join(sum1))
```

EDIT:

Just noticed you have the operands as ints, not strings. To use this technique, you should convert all the elements to strings. E.g.:

```
print (''.join([str(s) for s in sum1]))
```

Comment: I tried adding this and was given the following error message: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: @DaisyBradbury I think I just spotted the problem. Please see my edit.

Comment: I can't use this method as I need the value to stay as integers as I use it for a calculation later on in the program.

Comment: @DaisyBradbury you're just converting them for the sake of printing. In fact, we're printing a list comprehension based on `sum1`, not modifying `sum1` itself.

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Given you know the format, you can just use print with a format specifier:

```
>>> sum1 = (4, '*', 3)
>>> print("{}{}{}".format(*sum1))
4*3
```